# Java: multiple arrays

Tags: java, arrays

**What I am using:** I have multiple arrays

```
String[] cat = {"schema cat","schemacat","schemac"}
String[] dog = {"schema dog","schemadog","schemad"}
String[] horse = {"schema horse","schemachorse","schemah"}
```

I am getting a value to my method for example `schema cat` and I need to find in which array it is written. But I can sometimes get `schemac` or `cat` instead of `schema cat`.

**Problem:** So I need to find in which array is containing value.

**What I have tried:** I have tried writing multiple `if` cases but it's getting to messy and complicated. I am wondering what is the best solution for this case. I was thinking about switch, but don't know how to solve case situations.

Comment: Share the code of what you tried

Comment: All you need to do is use a loop to iterate over each array and check if `schema cat` exists in any array or not.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you want... do you need to get the string if it contains a substring? Then the Java method [`String.contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) is what you need.

Comment: I am using this to identify if I am getting cat/dog/horse. If I know which list gonna be the chosen one then I can say that it's cat or in other words get instance of cat or smth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simple create a method, where you give the `value`, the different `arrays` to look into, and iterate over them until you found the value

*Edit* : to get like the name of the array, you can add it as the first value of the array and use it as return value

```
static String whichArrayContains(String value, String[]... arrays) {
    for (String[] array : arrays) {
        if (Arrays.asList(array).contains(value)) {
            return array[0];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And use like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] cat = {"car", "schema cat", "schemacat", "schemac"};
    String[] dog = {"dog", "schema dog", "schemadog", "schemad"};
    String[] horse = {"horse", "schema horse", "schemachorse", "schemah"};
    String value = "schema cat";
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(whichArrayContains(value, cat, dog, horse)));   // cat
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(whichArrayContains(value, dog, horse)));        //null
}
```

Comment: Maybe you know if I can get array name?

Comment: @D1' you cannot do that

Comment: In such case then I can add cat element to array and then I will retrieve array I can get this element and say that it's cat

Comment: @D1' for sure, you can add it as first and the method will return the first element only, i’ll edit with this

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution would be to use lists, and a "reverse" maps, like:

```
Map<String, List<String>> listsByMembers = ...
```

The idea would be: instead of using arrays, you use Lists (just because collections work better with collections, instead of arrays). And then, for each member of each List, you do `listsByMembers.put(listEntry, theList)`.

Then you can do a simple lookup `listsByMembers.get("cat")` for example.

If we are talking about a **large** scale solution for real world problems, that would boil down to re-invent the wheel. For real-world scenarios, you should rather look into tools like Elastic, Solr, ...

Answer (score 0):

By using java8 streams concept you can solve your problem as shown below.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[]  args) {
        String[] cat = {"schema cat","schemacat","schemac"};
        String[] dog = {"schema dog","schemadog","schemad"};
        String[] horse = {"schema horse","schemachorse","schemah"};

        String testStr = "schemac";

        System.out.println(isStringExist(testStr, cat));

        System.out.println(isStringExist(testStr, dog));

        System.out.println(isStringExist(testStr, horse));
    }


    public static boolean isStringExist(String testStr, String[] items) {
        return Arrays.stream(items).parallel().anyMatch(testStr :: contains);
    }

}
```

In the above code isStringExist() method accepts the String array and test string that need to be compared with each String present inside the String array items and it returns a Boolean value which confirms that the string present in the String array that is passed to the method.

Comment: parallelStream()? Seriously?